# How to copy parent directory files to sub-directory using nodejs fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

While trying to copy the parent content to child directory its throwing the following error.Does anyone have any idea where I am doing wrong and is there any better approach to achieve this task?

main.js

```
   const fse = require('fs-extra');
    const copyDirectories = function(data) {
            let source ='/Users/Test';
            let destination = '/Users/Test/tmp';
            fse.copy(source, destination)
            .then(() => console.log('Copy completed!'))
            .catch( err => {
                console.log('An error occured while copying the folder.')
                return console.error(err)
            })
    
            return data;
         }
```

Error

```
 Cannot copy '/Users/Test' to a subdirectory of itself, '/Users/Test/tmp'.
```

Comment: First delete /Users/Test/tmp, then copy /Users/Test to /tmp/somethingrandom then move (rename) /tmp/somethingrandom to /Users/Test/tmp.    [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) has a mv (move) command.

Answer (score 1):

It is implicit that you will not copy the content of /Users/Test/tmp in /Users/Test/tmp/tmp (it is a recursion error, that throws the error message you get)

you have two options:

1. you copy /Users/Test to /tmp, then you move /tmp to /Users/Test/tmp (in case you have w+ access to /tmp)
2. you copy all the entries of /Users/Test excluding /Users/Test/tmp to /Users/Test/tmp

no other option I think.

A code example for option 2:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const fse = require('fs-extra');

const copyDirectories = (data, source, destination) => {
   fs.readdirSync(source,{withFileTypes: true}).filter(
       (entry) => {
           const fullsrc = path.resolve(source + path.sep + entry.name);
           const fulldest= path.resolve(destination + path.sep + entry.name);
           if(entry.isDirectory && fullsrc !== destination)
               fse.copySync(fullsrc, fulldest);
           else if(!entry.isDirectory)
               fs.copySync(fullsrc, fulldest);
           return true;
       }
   );
   return data;
}
```

Some comments:

1. I did not use the filter of fse.copy, because the non inclusion error is thrown before the filtering of the source directory dirents
2. I used Sync version, because the original code didn't look like async
3. I still don't get why there is a `data` parameter that is returned at the end of the function, but I kept it anyway

Answer (score 0):

first of all the child directory is the content of the parent directory. So, how can a child directory can store itself inside it? So, I think the good way to approach this problem is to copy all the contents of the parent directory except the child directory in which you want to copy all the contents.

Comment: thanks how do we do that new to fs module please help if you can